# laravel blade disable escape with substr method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

in Laravel 5 I'm trying to disable escaping in a Blade template which currently has the following:

```
{{ substr($v["CONTENT"],0,140)}}
```

I tried with

```
{{ !! substr($v["CONTENT"],0,140)}}
```

but it returns a 1 instead of a substring of text of 140 characters.
I cannot move the substr functions inside a controller because I'm inside of a loop:

```
@foreach($articleList as $k => $v)
```

any idea?

Comment: `{{ !! substr($v["CONTENT"],0,140) !! }}` ??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `{!!` and `!!}` to display unescaped data. There must not be any space between the curly brace and the exclamation points.

You're getting a `1` because your blade tags are wrong, and your `!!` is being treated as two `not` operators, which is equating to `{{ true }}`.

You want:

```
{!! substr($v["CONTENT"], 0, 140) !!}
```